# Output multi-dimensional array with brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, output

So I have this and I need to be able to output all of the arrays including brackets within the array.  The following example works by calling the index explicitly, but I can't seem to pass a function or a for loop where it is expecting an expression.  Also, a string will not do.

```
    for (var a in obj) {
    var dateArray = [];
    var date = new Date(obj[a]);
    // var date = new Date('March 29, 2016 14:00:00');
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    console.log(date.toString());
    console.log(hours);
    console.log(minutes);
    dateArray[0] = hours;
    dateArray[1] = minutes;
    disabled_time_list.push(dateArray);
}
for (var i = 0; i < disabled_time_list.length; i++) {
    console.log(disabled_time_list[i]);
}
pickertime.set('disable', [
    disabled_time_list[0]
    // [14,0],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought about that afterward, but wasn't sure it would be necessary.  Probably should have put it in the title as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever needs it, this is how I solved the problem:

```
$('.datepicker').change(function() {
    var datepicker = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
    var pickerdate = datepicker.pickadate('picker');
    var dateInput = pickerdate.get('value');

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://apptsch.dev/index.php/appointment/get_post_date',
        data: { date: dateInput }
    }).done(function(){
        disabled_time_list = [];
        var timepicker = $('.timepicker').pickatime();
        var pickertime = timepicker.pickatime('picker');
        var times_disabled = pickertime.get('disable');
        console.log(times_disabled);
        $.each(times_disabled,function( index, value) {
            pickertime.set('enable', [
                    times_disabled[index]
                ])
        }); // end re-enable previously disabled times

        var result = request.responseText;

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        for (var a in obj) {
            var dateArray = [];
            var date = new Date(obj[a]);

            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            dateArray[0] = hours;
            dateArray[1] = minutes;
            disabled_time_list.push(dateArray);
        }                    

        $.each(disabled_time_list,function( index, value ) {
            pickertime.set('disable', [

                disabled_time_list[index]

            ]); //end disable
      }); //end foreach
    }); //end ajax call
}); // end change
```